# Customize table of contents to get column-names

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
    \begin{document}
    \fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont {\tableofcontents{}} 
    \end{documents}
```

By this code, I get a simple table of contents:

**Contents**

1. **Introduction**             **1**
2. **Review of literature**     **3**

I want to put "**Page**" over page numbers, "**Sno.**" over numbers and "**Description**" over the section name. I am unable to find any similar relevant question here. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been very helpful to provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that showed your problem. The ToC you displayed was certainly not produced by the code snippet you posted.

As I have no idea what you have done the MWE below is based in the normal ToC layout but with your column names printed.

```
% tocheadsprob.tex  SE 576103

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
    \begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
  \\[\baselineskip]Sno Description \hfill Page}
    \fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont {\tableofcontents{}} 

\section{Introduction}
\clearpage
\section{Review}

    \end{document}
```

This should give you an idea of how you can meet your desired layout but you will have to configure the layouts to suit your vision.

[image]